# How to make UITableView re-evaluate the need of a footer for a specific section?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a dynamic UITableView where I programmatically add rows and then I call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.

The problem is, before the rows are added, I have a section footer. This section footer is no longer needed after the rows are inserted.

Is there any method that will force the UITableView to ask it's source again whether or not it needs that footer? Or maybe a way for me to manually remove it?

As a workaround I called `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` but obviously that is not optimal since it's rendering my first call useless (I could call only reloadSections but it might be too much processing when I'm only adding rows - not to mention animation issues).

In a perfect world, I'd have a way to make the UITableView call for `tableView(_:viewForFooterInSection:)` again.

Ps [1]: Just reinforcing that i'm dealing with footerInSection, not tableViewFooter.

Ps [2]: Sorry for the horrible title.

Comment: Try using `reloadSections` instead of `insertRows` when going from 0 rows with the footer to X rows without the footer.

Comment: In fact, I don't have the state "0 rows with footer". There's always at least one row always and footer can vary. I'm trying not to call `reloadSections` always because at some point the table can have like 30-40 rows and calling `reloadSections` at that point would be bad, right?

Comment: You would only need to call `reloadSections` for one section and when that section's footer needs to either appear or disappear. Keep using `insertRows` when the footer doesn't need to change.

Comment: Oh, it makes sense. I just didn't build with that in mind. I guess I'm gonna have to re-think a couple of things. Thanks.